# ¿Como enviar mas de una query en un reportDataSource.Value para reportviewer?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Tengo el siguiente código como ejemplo:

```
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
reportDataSource.Value = query;
```

Actualmente envío una query al .rdlc dentro a una tabla, pero me gustaría saber como enviar mas de una query o un array o lista. En el .rdlc, mi objetivo es listar una tabla que muestra ciertos números, y agrupado por el numero, mostrar dentro de ella otra tabla que contiene datos de detalle de lo que empece a mostrar.

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna idea de como hacerlo

Answer (score 3):

Debes crear mas `reportDataSource`, con nombre, y agregarlos en el `reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);` los nombre de cada source debe ser el mismo que tiene en el reporte.